# Storing & Querying Location data (geo/gis/etc) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, mapkit, postgis

I need to record and track location of some entities in a Rails app. Simply put, iPhone will post its location (lat/long) and Rails will archive it. Then when queried Rails will need to return resources by proximity to some arbitrary location. Calculations will be minimal (distance from point) initially.

What's the latest, greatest & easiest way to handle this? Options I'm aware of...

1. I could brute force it by capturing
   lat/long and doing proximity
   calculations myself
2. There's this [Geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/)
   gem/plugin though it doesn't appear
   to have been updated **since 2009(!?!)** and isn't verified with Ruby 1.9.2.
3. There's **PostGIS** as a backend
   database extension though wondering what value
   this adds and if it merits the additional overhead it may require?
4. Others?

Answer (score 1):

I vote on #2, GeoKit: Since its the simplest and requires no deployment of additional software/search engine/database.

Rails Geokit DOES WORK in rails 3 with ruby 1.9.2
You just have to follow the instructions on this issue:
https://github.com/andre/geokit-rails/issues#issue/15

Do what **tute** and **brianlong** are suggesting.

Furthermore, I submitted a fix to make sort_by_distance work for :through associations:

https://github.com/andre/geokit-rails/issues#issue/26

Comment: order of answers jumps around on this site so not sure what "I vote on 2" means... can you be more specific so other readers don't *have* to follow links...

Comment: Number 2 refers to your list from the question: Geokit, but Ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is using MongoDB an option? It supports GIS stuff out of the box - Mongoid lets you query it like

```
Address.near(:position => [ 37.7, -122.4, 10 ])
```

More details on the Mongoid site [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/)

Comment: Anything is an option at this stage... I've been hearing alot of great things about Mongo...but shy away from "document" centric...mostly cuz I haven't used it and don't understand it.  If it's a better option for object-oriented programming then it's high time I investigate. Nice to hear it has GIS stuff. You using it in production?  Any good links to help migrate my mind from world of related tables & columns to 'documents'?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking Sphinx can index on lat/lon and return results [within a search radius](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/geosearching.html).

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but with Thinking Sphinx could I go about building app 'traditionally' (with MySQL, Postgres, etc.) and store lat/lon info in a table then at some point implement TS and index on lat/lon to get functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, Thinking Sphinx (using the Sphinx engine) builds indexes from relational databases, so you would just store the lat/lon like any other data in tables. One quirk is the lat/lon is stored as floats in radians rather than degrees, and distances are expressed in meters.  But you don't need any specialized spatial database extensions, just a plain old SQL database. The indexing is done in a background process.